# python apschedular RedisJobStore not storing jobs in redis cache

Tags: python-3.x, redis, apscheduler

That is my python code: All jobs are triggering at right time but not stored as redis cache. If restart the program, cannot schedule pending jobs. What I am doing wrong?

```
from apscheduler.jobstores.redis import RedisJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

if __name__ == '__main__':

    jobstores = {
        'redis': RedisJobStore(jobs_key='dispatched_trips_jobs', run_times_key='dispatched_trips_running', host='localhost', port=6379)
    }
    executors = {
        'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(100),
        'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
    }

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors)


    scheduler.start()

    while True:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't see any code that adds jobs. It seems like this snippet is not representative of your real application.

Comment: Are you sure you're adding your jobs to the redis job store and not the default one?

Comment: Jobs are added from other code snippet. All jobs are triggering well. No problem from this part. Problem is the jobs are not saved to redis so that, in case of restart of program can schedule the job again. Do you really need to seed how the jobs are added?

Comment: Yes, because I suspect that you are not specifying which job store they should be added to, in which case they go to the "default" store (which is a memory based job store) instead of "redis" which you have configured here.

Comment: Thanks @AlexGrönholm a lot!, You are right. I changed the code lines from

`jobstores = {
        'redis': RedisJobStore(jobs_key='dispatched_trips_jobs', run_times_key='dispatched_trips_running', host='localhost', port=6379)
    }` 
to 

`jobstores = {
        'default': RedisJobStore(jobs_key='dispatched_trips_jobs', run_times_key='dispatched_trips_running', host='localhost', port=6379)
    }`

And Its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the lines

```
jobstores = {
    'redis': RedisJobStore(jobs_key='dispatched_trips_jobs', run_times_key='dispatched_trips_running', host='localhost', port=6379)
}
```

to

```
jobstores = {
    'default': RedisJobStore(jobs_key='dispatched_trips_jobs', run_times_key='dispatched_trips_running', host='localhost', port=6379)
}
```

works fine